# universe inconsistency with sumbool

Tags: coq

I have defined and proven the following lemma:

```
    NM.In k m -> {NM.In k m0}+{NM.In k m1}.
```

I can also prove a symmetric lemma for:

```
    {NM.In k m0}+{NM.In k m1} -> NM.In k m
```

However when I try to combine them into one as:

```
    NM.In k m <-> {NM.In k m0}+{NM.In k m1}.
```

I got the following error:

```
The term "sumbool (@NM.In CarrierA k m0) (@NM.In CarrierA k m1)" has type 
"Set" while it is expected to have type "Prop" (universe inconsistency: Cannot enforce
Set = Prop).
```

How this could be solved?

Comment: It's not really a universe inconsistency, it's a type mismatch: `<->` aka `iff` only accepts `Prop` arguments.

Comment: `impl` is also `Prop -> Prop -> Prop`

Comment: But `->` is not `impl` - it's a builtin that accepts any types (well actually, `A -> B` is builtin syntactic sugar for `forall _ : A, B`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out, the problem is that the `<->` connective only takes propositions as arguments, while `sumbool` lives in `Set`.  This can be circumvented in a few ways: you can replace `sumbool` with `or`, or you can replace `iff` with a computationally relevant connective:

```
Variables A B C : Prop.

Check (({A} + {B} -> C) * (C -> {A} + {B}))%type.
```